# Why does FrameLayout not show when I use setLayoutParams?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use FrameLayout to put a view above the other one in a table (2 frame layouts per row) but I need to add some params to it (margins, width and height). The problem is that adding the params to it prevents it from showing.
For the example, I only put 1 view in it but it is only because I tried to simplify it so I can post it.

When using the code in the example, it doesn't show the FrameLayout but if I remove the `frameLayout.setLayoutParams(frameParams);` line, I can't choose it's size and margin size

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        button.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        button.setText("Button2");
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200,100);
        frameParams.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(frameParams);
        frameLayout.addView(button);
        row.addView(frameLayout);
        tableLayout.addView(row);
```

How can I fix this or is there a different type of layout/container that I should use instead of FrameLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

framelayout is inside TabbleRow so you should use

```
TabbleRow.LayoutParams frameParams = new TabbleRow.LayoutParams(200,100);
```

Comment: it doesn't change the size of the button and the margins (even if I use setMargins with it)

Comment: you should also set layout params for button with Framelayout.LayouParams